# foreach multidimensional Array and insert database

Tags: php

got a problem.
I got form like this

```
<input name="product[sub_name][]">
<input name="product[price][]">
<input name="product[random][]">
<input name="product[just_field][]">
```

I can add many blocks of this form pressing "add more".
Recieving posta data i do the stuff.

```
$field = $_POST['product'];

foreach ($field as $key => $values) {

    foreach($values as $value) {

        $key.' - '.$value;


    }

}
```

I need code to insert multiple rows in database depending on posted rows. Problem is that, i dont know how to get only, for example, "price". Goal is insert all data in database. Hope you guys understand my logic.

Here is print_r output. I can got more possibilities than two

```
Array ( 
    [sub_name] => Array ( [0] => New car [1] => New bike )
    [standart_price] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 300 )
    [cupon_price] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 200 )
    [max_purchases] => Array ( [0] => 1000 [1] => 100 )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a more ordered result if you re-organize the array to contain the index first:

```
<input name="product[$index][sub_name]">
<input name="product[$index][price]">
<input name="product[$index][random]">
<input name="product[$index][just_field]">
```

Each time you add a new product change the index with javascript, in that way, when you recieve the data in php you can do something like:

```
$products = $_POST['product'];

foreach ($products as $product)
{
    $sub_name = $product['sub_name'];
    $random = $product['random'];
    $just_field = $product['just_field'];

    $sql = "Your SQL query"

    $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Maybe need a little more work changing the html indexes with javascript but your code become more clear.

p.s. That's the general idea, i don't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
print_r($_POST["product"]);
```

to output the whole array.

Are you sure the values transmitted by the formular are passed into $_POST ?

Could you please post the output.

Comment: Here is it

 Array ( 
  [sub_name] => Array ( [0] => New car [1] => New bike )
  [standart_price] => Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 300 )
  [cupon_price] => Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 200 )
  [max_purchases] => Array ( [0] => 1000 [1] => 100 )
  )

Answer (score 0):

Check this out..

```
<?

//Connect to DB.
$link = mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//Consider your table structure in MYSQL. Don't depend on this structure.
//CREATE TABLE TBL1(SLNO PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, DETAIL_VALUE VARCHAR(200));
foreach( $_POST['product'] as $key => $value )
{
    //Get specific Tag.
    if( $key == 'price')
    {
        //Creating Query to insert. 
        $query = "insert into TBL1('DETAIL_VALUE') VALUES('".addslashes($value)."')";
        $mysqli_query($link, $query) or die;
    }
}


?>
```

For more details on querys or php: Refer PHP.net.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "db name");

$field = $_POST['product'];

foreach ($field['price'] as $idx => $price)
{
    $sub_name = $field['sub_name'][$idx];
    $random = $field['random'][$idx];
    $just_field = $field['just_field'][$idx];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (sub_name, random, just_field, price) VALUES ('{$sub_name}','{$random}','{$just_field}','{$price}')";

    $mysqli->query($sql);


}
```